# Twilio IP Messaging - get the last message index on REST API

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

Using the twilio-ruby package to connect to the REST API for Twilio's IP Messaging service and attempting to compute an unread message count.

The REST API is paginating the messages so that something like

```
channel.messages.list.last.index
```

Will return 49 once there are more than 50 messages in the channel.

Is there a way to get just the last message on the channel (as seems to be possible in the android/ios SDK) to avoid paginating through all message history?

Answer (score 1):

In regards to computing an unread message count, take a look at the [Message Consumption Horizon](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/ip-messaging/guides/consumption-horizon) and subtract the `lastConsumedMessageIndex` from the total number of messages in the list - 1.

For the messages list (in Python):

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/ip-messaging/rest/messages#list-all-messages

```
# Download the Python helper library from twilio.com/docs/python/install
from twilio.rest.ip_messaging import TwilioIpMessagingClient

# Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
account = "ACCOUNT_SID"
token = "AUTH_TOKEN"
client = TwilioIpMessagingClient(account, token) 

service = client.services.get(sid="SERVICE_SID")
channel = service.channels.get(sid="CHANNEL_ID")
messages = channel.messages.list()
```

See also, [Sending a Consumption Report](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/ip-messaging/guides/consumption-horizon#sending-a-consumption-report) (the example in JavaScript):

```
//determine the newest message index
var newestMessageIndex = activeChannel.messages.length ? 
    activeChannel.messages[activeChannel.messages.length-1].index : 0;
//check if we we need to set the consumption horizon
if (activeChannel.lastConsumedMessageIndex !== newestMessageIndex) {
    activeChannel.updateLastConsumedMessageIndex(newestMessageIndex);
}
```

Comment: thanks, I was able to set and retrieve the lastConsumedMessageIndex for Members and do the subtraction to get an unread count. However, my concern was with getting the total number of messages without paginating through all of them on the REST API.  if the next line in your example is to use `len(messages)` would that also return 50 (the number of results returned from the REST API?)

Comment: Ah gotcha, yes it would return the results for the current page of 50. The API does not currently provide a way to get the total number of messages in channel without paginating.